# Range of inverse circular functions

Tags: functions

I have read that $2\operatorname{arc}(\tan x)=\operatorname{arc}(\sin(2x/(1+x^2)))$. Now the range of $2 \operatorname{arc}(\tan x)$ should be $(-\pi,\pi)$ but that of $\operatorname{arc}(\sin(2x/(1+x^2)))$ remains $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. How is this possible? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You have been a member for two months. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: The identity is not valid for all $x$. It is valid for $x$ between $-1$ and $+1$.